# Laravel: Column selection, column not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible, in Laravel eloquent, that whenever I select specific columns from the database, and a column does not exists, MySQL will ignore this column and still continue?

I currently want to have a ?fields selector in the url, but if there's a typo or somewhat I just want it to ignore that column even though it is trying to select that column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without code you will get no help.. 
Show what have you tried and we can help you!

Comment: what you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify a list of columns you want to fetch, e.g. by passing it to **get()** or **select()** methods of a query builder, Eloquent trusts that you know what you are doing and uses this list you provided to generate an SQL query. **It's not possible** for Eloquent to filter the list of columns and remove non-existent columns - **Eloquent does not have any knowledge about columns that exist in the database**.

If you want it to work, you'll need to implement such filtering mechanism yourself - you could store a list of columns somewhere in your model/config/etc. and filter the list before passing it to Eloquent builder.